# How to use table checkbox select all functionality for 2 table in single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this table actually, the select all and column-wise selection are working perfectly using class and ids, how to reconfigure this for multiple tables on a single page without repeating the js code? seeking for suggestions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Check all rows
  $('#check_all').click(function() {
    $('input').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  // Check all columns
  $('.check_column').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('th').index();
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('.check_row').each(function() {
      var checkboxes = $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox');
      checkboxes.eq(index).prop('checked', isChecked);
    });
  });

  $('.check_row').click(function() {
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox');
    checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tableOne">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="check_all" class="check_all">
          <label for="check_all">All All</label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="column_01" class="check_column">
          <label for="column_01">All column</label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="column_02" class="check_column">
          <label for="column_02">All column</label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="column_03" class="check_column">
          <label for="column_03">All column</label>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="column_04" class="check_column">
          <label for="column_04">All column</label>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="row_01" class="check_row">
          <label for="row_01">Check row</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="access_01" name="permissions[]">
        <label for="access_01">Access</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_02" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_02">Edit</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_03" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_03">Create</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_04" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_04">Delete</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="row_02" class="check_row">
          <label for="row_02">Check row</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="access_05" name="permissions[]">
        <label for="access_05">Access</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_06" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_06">Edit</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_07" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_07">Create</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_08" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_08">Delete</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="row_03" class="check_row">
          <label for="row_03">Check row</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="access_09" name="permissions[]">
        <label for="access_09">Access</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_10" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_10">Edit</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_11" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_11">Create</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_12" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_12">Delete</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="row_04" class="check_row">
          <label for="row_04">Check row</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="access_13" name="permissions[]">
        <label for="access_13">Access</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_14" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_14">Edit</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_15" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_15">Create</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="input_outer">
          <input type="checkbox" id="access_16" name="permissions[]">
          <label for="access_16">Delete</label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get rid of all the `id`s in the table and use only `class`es. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Check all rows
    $('.check_all').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('table')
            .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    // Check all columns
    $('.check_column').click(function () {
        var column = $(this).closest('th').index() + 1;

        $(this).closest('table')
            .find('tbody > tr > td:nth-child(' + column + ')')
            .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });

    // Check all rows
    $('.check_row').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr')
            .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_all"> All All</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_row"> Check row</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Access</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Edit</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Create</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Delete</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_row"> Check row</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Access</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Edit</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Create</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Delete</label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_all"> All All</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
            <th><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_column"> All column</label></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_row"> Check row</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Access</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Edit</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Create</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Delete</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="check_row"> Check row</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Access</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Edit</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Create</label></td>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"> Delete</label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```